# How to get resolved data into my navbar which is outside of the <ng-view> element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my simplified index.html setup.

```
<nav ng-controller="NavController">
{{ username }}
</nav>
<div ng-view></div>
```

I have a Session service that stores the username data and is initialized when the route is being resolved.  The problem is that my route resolver happens only before controllers used in ng-view and not before my NavController.

So when routing occurs, the NavController looks at the Session service and sees that it hasn't been initialized and can't retrieve the username from it, while the controller used in ng-view waits until the information is available before displaying.

I guess the general question is, if we use services to share information between controllers, how would I share information to my NavController if it relies on information that may not be available yet when it initializes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put watcher on service variable like this on your $onInit in controller:

```
$scope.$watch('SessionService.username', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal) { 
      $scope.username = newVal;
    }
  });
```

Another thing, if you use ui-router, you could specifiy `resolve` on your route, this way route won't be resolved until your resolves are ready.

Comment: The $watch worked but I had to put the SessionService on $scope first which makes sense.

I was using resolve from NgRoute but like I mentioned the controller in the route was resolving after my NavController was ready.  Would ui-router make sure both were ready some how before continuing?

Comment: If you use resolve on ui-router state it will make sure that those bindings defined in resolve are finished before loading the state.